# Saving a program as a .exe file in Visual Studio 2017 with using no programs

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to save a program in Visual Studio 2017 as a `.exe` file so I can send it by e-mail. You can save it as a `.sln` and as a `.vb` file (I'm using VB.NET) but I can't find any way to save it as a `.exe` file inside the program. I also don't want to use any downloadable programs that can do this.

Comment: It's called `compilation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the solution.
Open the folder that the solution is in.
Navigate to the Bin folder.
Under this folder there will likely be a folder called Debug (or a name that corresponds to your build configuration). In here will be your exe file if it built correctly and you have the correct type of visual studio project.